# How can I stack bootstrap buttons on mobile

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 buttons that I want to display 2x2 on web browsers and then stack on top of eachother on mobile and maybe tablet. I read about using btn-primary and secondary and also button block, but I am having no luck. Any direction on the easiest way to achieve this?

```html
    <div class="button-group ">    
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-primary page-scroll" href="#intro">watch video</button>
                 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-secondary">review info</button>
            </div>
            <div class="button-group ">  
                 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-primary">see sample</button>
                 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-secondary">sequence</button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bootstrap's [`.btn-group`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) component allows you to use eighter horizontal or vertical styled `.btn-group` at a time but not both.

Use media query and override styles.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.btn-group {margin-bottom: 10px;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .btn-group {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .btn-group .btn {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">    
  <button class="btn btn-primary" href="#intro">watch video</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">review info</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-group ">  
  <button class="btn btn-primary">see sample</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">sequence</button>
</div>
```

Comment: how do i get the 2 sections to stack on each other? watch video still needs to be on top of review and see sample needs to be on top on sequence in web version instead of side by side

Comment: @vzupo sorry, I didn't get your words.. you can remove `margin` that I added in styles to remove the gap.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS @media query to reposition the layout of the buttons on mobile devices...